# url not found - Django

Tags: django, url

I'm getting "URL not found error" on my website. These are my files:

myapp.urls:

```
url(r'^produkty/', include('supplement.urls', namespace='supplements')),
```

supplement.urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', SupplementDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
url(r'^$', SupplementListView.as_view(), name='list'),]
```

supplement.views:

```
class SupplementListView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Supplement.objects.all()

class SupplementDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Supplement.objects.all()
```

NOTE: Both queryset = Supplement.objects.all() and get_queryset(self): return Supplement.objects.all() don't work in SupplementDetailView

supplement.models:

```
class Supplement(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, help_text=_("product's name"), max_length=50)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    portion = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, help_text=_("portion"))
    img = models.ImageField(default='kitchen/No-image-available.jpg', upload_to='products/', blank=True, null=True)
    description = RichTextField()
    contains = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=3000, help_text=_("contains"))
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('supplements:detail', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-name']
        verbose_name = _('supplement')
        verbose_name_plural = _('supplements')

def rl_pre_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = unique_slug_generator(instance)


pre_save.connect(rl_pre_save_receiver, sender=Supplement)
```

Templates for SupplementListView and SupplementDetailView are placed in BASE_DIR/supplement/templates/supplement.

NOTE: SupplementDetailView works like a charm. It loads the information about product passed in a  in url (for example: myapp.pl/produkty/product-slug), but the list of products (myapp.pl/produkty) returns "URL not found error"

Thank You for your help in advance, I've been struggling with that error for quite a while now.

Comment: You haven't said what URL you are calling

Comment: myapp.pl/produkty/, defined in myapp's urls file: url(r'^produkty/', include('supplement.urls', namespace='supplements')),
and then in supplement.urls (urls of the specific app I want to open):
url(r'^$', SupplementListView.as_view(), name='list')

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found the answer: I had this in my myapp.urls file:

```
url(r'^', include('opinions.urls', namespace='home')),    
url(r'^produkty/', include('supplement.urls', namespace='supplements')),
```

so whenever I entered "myapp.pl/produkty/" Django was convinced, that "produkty" is a slug for opinion model. I switched both url patterns (so the pattern for namespace='supplements' is loaded first) and everything works great.